# Should I set validator or rpc nodes in chainspec bootnodes?

Tags: chainspec, bootnode

I am adding bootnodes to chainspecs and I wonder if I should prefer setting validator nodes or rpc nodes in the bootnodes list. They are all connected with p2p, but is there a reason to privilege some over the other for network discovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are all connected with p2p, but is there a reason to privilege some over the other for network discovery?

No, not really. Having dedicated nodes as boot nodes would be more "clean", but there is no strict requirement. As you already said, they are all connected to each other any way!